# Tensorflow 2: StringLookUp or categorical_column_with_vocabulary_list

Tags: tensorflow, machine-learning, data-science, tensorflow2.0, categorical-data

I saw in many tutorials in the Tensorflow 2 documentation, that they use two different functions to deal with categorical features:

- tf.keras.layers.experimental.preprocessing.**StringLookup**
- tf.feature_column.**categorical_column_with_vocabulary_list**

From what I've seen, they work very similarly and they are used for the same things... And I have also seen that **categorical_column_with_vocabulary_list** existed in Tensorflow 1, but **StringLookUp** didn't.

Is anyone experienced with these two functions and able to explain their advantages/disadvantages from each other?

Thank you very much.